# GitHub pages not publishing my page

Tags: github-pages

When I try to access the page at https://fabio-laf.github.io/graph-visualization/, it says "404 There isn't a GitHub Pages site here".Am I doing something wrong? The page repo is https://github.com/Fabio-LaF/graph-visualization.

Note: I have already published a page in GitHub pages that works just fine and the settings seem to be the same as this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working now. You saw 404 because your 404 was cached by your browser. Try open it with incognito mode or clear your browser cache.

If you want to purge GitHub pages cache you can trigger a new build by:

```
git commit -m 'rebuild pages' --allow-empty
git push origin <branch-name>
```